# Numeric value (9000000000000) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647) in splunk

Tags: splunk

Because I have very large data, I changed the value of maxresultrows
[change maxresultrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2x9W.png)

But when I use the dbxquery command, I get the following error. Is there a solution?
[show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4wLG.jpg)

Comment: 9 *trillion* rows? What kind of database query would every return 9 *trillion* rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set `maxresultrows` to a value in the specified range.

Also, be aware of this note about `maxresultrows` in limits.conf.spec:

> This limit should not exceed 50000.

Answer (score 0):

A (64 bit machine) integer has a size of 4 bytes or 32 bits. The first bit is reserved for the sign. So there are only 2^31-1 (=2147483647) positive integers (excluding 0) and 2^31 (=2147483648) negative integers. It is like trying to write the number 12345 with only 4 digits.

Of course there are exceptions to the size of integers, but most languages standardized them to always be 4 bytes long.